# Error when trying to convert .sxw file to .rml in OpenERP 6.0.3

Tags: python, odoo

```
[2012-06-01 15:33:10,638][molisamples] ERROR:web-services:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 122, in wrapper
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 176, in execute
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 167, in execute_cr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.0\Server\addons\base_report_designer\base_report_designer.py", line 42, in sxwtorml
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.0\Server\addons\base_report_designer\openerp_sxw2rml\openerp_sxw2rml.py", line 309, in sxw2rml
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.0\Server\addons\base_report_designer\openerp_sxw2rml\openerp_sxw2rml.py", line 294, in unpackNormalize
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.0\Server\addons\base_report_designer\openerp_sxw2rml\openerp_sxw2rml.py", line 269, in oo_read
  File "zipfile.pyo", line 346, in init
  File "zipfile.pyo", line 366, in _GetContents
  File "zipfile.pyo", line 378, in _RealGetContents
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

I get the above error when I try to convert a report I just designed to .rml (using Open Office Writer). Please what could be the issue. I am seriously confused here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had some errors in the python parser file for the report. That's what was causing the issue. It's been fixed now. Thanks y'all for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your .sxw to .rml using base_report_designer module.

Try following steps:

Open terminal -> go to openerp_sxw2rml folder like this:

**cd addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml**

Then run this command: python openerp_sxw2rml.py absolute path of sxw > absolute path of rml

Like this:

**python openerp_sxw2rml.py /home/arya/my_module/report/my_report.sxw > /home/arya/my_module/report/my_report.rml**

This will convert sxw file into rml and you can find your file at given path of rml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the file is not a zip file, so it's probably expecting the compressed format of sxw file. Any chance you saved the file in OpenOffice's uncompressed format?

Comment: How do I know if it's in compressed format or not? I just created a new sxw file and started my report. Do I need to use a template or something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you save in Openoffice Writer, you select the old format, the one with SXW extension.

Don't just type .sxw, make sure the program puts it there by itself by selecting the correct entry in the fileformat selectionbox (i forget the full title and cannot check atm)